# yeoman webapp generator grunt sass --trace

Tags: sass, yeoman

im looking for a way to see the line errors in sass.
it just keeps telling me:

```
Warning: Running "sass:server" (sass) task Use --force to continue.
    Aborted due to warnings.
```

but grunt serve --trace doesnt work
neither does a tweak in the Gruntfile

i'm using the yeoman webapp-generator

Answer (score 1):

Long time, but maybe somebody still needs a hint. I could fix it by re-installing sass:

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-sass
```

Now the Sass error messages will be more useful and most likely point to the exact error.